# How to show connection is secure (SSL) in website?

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, mkcert

I have created the self sign certificated with the help of mkcert for my ip address then I access the website which i place in the tomcat when I access this in my local computer its shows me i.e https://idAddress:8443 connection is secure but when i want to access this website in local network another pc its not show me connection is secure but show me not secure https://ipAddress:8443

How can i access the secure connection, when i access the website in another machine its show me secure connection

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but when i want to access this website in local network another pc its not show me connection is secure but show me not secure `https://ipAddress:8443`

That's probably happening **because** you used a self-signed certificate.  (If you click on the icon in the browser window that is labeling the URL as insecure, the browser should be able to tell you why it thinks it is insecure.)

Under many circumstances, self-signed certs are insecure. For example ... if some random person sent you that URL in an email. Your browser is just being conservative. And rightly so.  It has no way of knowing who really signed the cert ... and whether the user is likely to be doing something unsafe by connecting to it.

If you want other people to trust your site ... and not have it show up as "insecure", you need to invest in a proper domain name and a proper SSL certificate for that domain.